# Conjugacy classes as left Kan extension of forgetful functor

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, conjugacy-classes, kan-extension

Let $\mathbf{Set}$, $\mathbf{Grp}$, and $\mathbf{Grp}^{\rm conj}$ denote the categories of sets and functions, groups and homomorphisms, and groups and homomorphisms up to conjugation, respectively. (Thus the fundamental group is a functor from path-connected spaces to the latter.)

Let $X$ be the forgetful functor from $\mathbf{Grp}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$, $A$ the obvious functor from $\mathbf{Grp}$ to $\mathbf{Grp}^{\rm conj}$, and $L$ the functor from $\mathbf{Grp}^{\rm conj}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$ sending a group to its set of conjugacy classes. Then is $L$ the left Kan extension of $X$ along $A$?

Answer (score 14):

$\newcommand{\Gp}{\mathbf{Grp}}
\newcommand{\conj}{^{\mathbf{conj}}} 
\newcommand{\Gpd}{\mathbf{Gpd}}
\newcommand{\Set}{\mathbf{Set}}
\newcommand{\ho}{\mathrm{ho}}
\newcommand{\Fun}{\mathrm{Fun}}
\newcommand{\Lan}{\mathrm{Lan}}
\newcommand{\colim}{\mathrm{colim}}
$
Yes. There is a "by-hands proof", where you just compute the colimits that are involved, but there turns out to be a nice proof if you go to $(2,1)$-categories. Namely, $\Gp\conj$ is equivalent to the homotopy category of a natural $(2,1)$-category: its objects are groups, its $1$-morphisms are group morphisms, and its $2$-morphisms are conjugations : if $f,g: G\to Q$ are morphisms, a $2$-morphism $f\implies g$ is an element $q\in Q$ such that $f^q = g$ (where $f^q : qf(-)q^{-1}$).

I'm going to call this $\Gpd$, and it's relatively easy to observe that $\Gp \simeq \Gpd_{1/}$ in a way that the functor $A$ can be identified with the composite $\Gp\simeq \Gpd_{1/}\to \Gpd\to \ho(\Gpd)\simeq \Gp\conj$.

Because $\Set$ is a $1$-category, restriction along $\Gpd\to\ho(\Gpd)$ induces an equivalence $\Fun(\ho(\Gpd),\Set)\to \Fun(\Gpd,\Set)$, so that left Kan extension is "silly": it's the observation that the functor factors through $\ho$.

Therefore, it suffices to prove that the left Kan extension of $\Gpd_{1/}\to \Set$ along $\Gpd_{1/}\to\Gpd$ is given by the set of conjugacy classes. But now we can reap the benefits of this approach: $\Gpd_{1/}\to\Gpd$ is a left fibration (as is $C_{x/}\to C$ for any $(\infty,1)$-category $C$ and object $x$), so that the left Kan extension of a functor $f:\Gpd_{1/}\to \Set$ along $p:\Gpd_{1/}\to \Gpd$ is given at $G$ by the colimit over the fiber of $f$ (note that $\Gp\to \Gp\conj$ is *not* a left fibration).

More precisely: $\Lan_p f(G) = \colim_{\alpha \in p^{-1}(G)} f(1\xrightarrow{\alpha} G)$. Here, $f(1\to G)$ is just the underlying set of $G$, and the $1$-groupoid $p^{-1}(G)$ is equivalent to $BG$, and it acts on $G=f(1\xrightarrow{\alpha} G) $ by conjugacy, so that this colimit is the quotient of $G$ by its conjugacy action.

So $\Lan_p X$ is the functor from $\Gpd$ to $\Set$ that sends $G$ to its set of conjugacy classes, and this factors through $\ho(\Gpd)\simeq \Gp\conj$ in the appropriate way.

Comment: This is such a beautiful proof!

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to Maxime's sophisticated proof is to observe that $X$ and $L$ are both corepresented by the free group, because a group homomorphism from a free group (up to conjugacy) is the same as choosing an element (up to conjugacy).
That is, $X = \hom_{\mathrm{Grp}}(\mathbb{Z},-)$ and $L = \hom_{\mathrm{Grp}^{\mathrm{conj}}}(A(\mathbb{Z}),-)$.

In general, the left Kan extension of a (co)representable functor is the (co)representable functor by the image of the representing object (this is the naturality of the Yoneda embedding).
See [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension#LeftKanOnRepresentables) for example.

Putting the two together, we get the required equivalence:
$$
A_!X
= A_!\hom_{\mathrm{Grp}}(\mathbb{Z},-)
= \hom_{\mathrm{Grp}^\mathrm{conj}}(A(\mathbb{Z}),-)
= L
$$

Comment: Ah that is way faster. I got confused because $Grp \to Grp^{conj}$ was not a fibration, but it of course doesn't change anything (this is obviously *the* correct answer, btw - except maybe if you want to compute more complicated $A_!$'s )